# Fetching Web Page Data Python

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I wanted to fetch some data from say...http://fangraphs.com. I want to fetch a random player's home run total for this year. Is there a way to do this in Python, or should I use a different language for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called web scraping. Python is as good as any other language for scraping, if not better.

For the actual parsing, try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), as it can parse malformed HTML and has simple-to-understand functions for extracting things.